how to use micrometer as a replacement of sleuth decorate queues with sprint boot 3.2.6
I was using mvn dependency in spring boot 2.* application
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

and sleuth configuration as below in application.yml
  sleuth:
    reactor:
      instrumentation-type: DECORATE_QUEUES

Now I migrated the application to spring boot version 3.2.6 where sleuth is not supported.
I have been trying to follow the steps given
here
but I am getting some weired error of snakeyaml reading, which points at my configuration
which is as :
    spring:
      reactor:
        context-propagation: AUTO

I also validated yaml file here
